# Trying to output a list but instead getting a single value

Tags: list, functional-programming, racket

- I'm trying to create a function that compares two lists of strings and saves the comparison results into a list
- the results are given in boolean
  there are no error messages and instead of the output being a list with multiple boolean results I get only one result

```
; alon: a list of names
; alob: a list of boolean 
(define (findNamev4 alon alon2 alob)  
  (cond
    [(empty? alon) #false]
    [(string=? (first alon) (first alon2)) (cons #true lob)]
    [else (findNamev4 (rest alon) (first (rest alon2)) alob)]))
    
    
(findNamev4 l1 l2 lob)
(findNamev4 l2 l2 lob)
```

- the output is not a list but instead a single boolean value

```
(list #true)
(list #true)
(list #true)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `(first (rest alon2))` as the second argument of your recursive step?

Comment: can you show the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing this as follows:

```lisp
(define (compare-string-lists strs-1 strs-2)
  (cond
   [(or (empty? strs-1) (empty? strs-2)) empty]
   [else
    (cons (string=? (first strs-1) (first strs-2))
          (compare-string-lists (rest strs-1) (rest strs-2)))]))
```

You didn't specify what should happen if the lists have different lengths; this version will only compare as many elements as are present in the shorter of the two lists.

An explanation:

- The first case is our base case. If either of the two lists are empty, then there's no comparisons we need to add to our comparison list so we can return an empty list.
- The second case is our recursive case. We want to compare the first elements of each of the lists, and then tack on the result (using `cons`) to the list containing the comparison results of the remaining parts of our input lists.